# The "Since... then" construction

Tags: grammaticality, logic

Is the construction "Since... then" correct? E.g.

> **Since** it's a right triangle, **then** the Pythagorean theorem holds.

It sounds and feels wrong to me, and I think someone once told me it's wrong, but I haven't been able to find a definitive answer anywhere online. I see this construction used from time to time within mathematics.

Comment: Since you heard a mathematician say it, then it doesn't mean it's good English.  The same goes for computer geeks, some of whom can't  seem to build an English sentence that has an "if" but no "then".

Comment: import @BrianHitchcock; Ha = "Those are basic programmers";  If youAskMe { they(); use(); a(); silly(); syntax(); }

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I agree. But since I've heard it so many times, then it might actually not be wrong, just uncommon.

Answer (score 23):

*Since* is synonymous to *because* in this case.
Your sentence is therefore equivalent to

> *Because it's a right triangle, then the Pythagorean theorem holds.

There are two words indicating a causal relationship, *because* and *then*. That's one too many.

You can use either of these two:

> Since it's a right triangle, the Pythagorean theorem holds.
>   If it's a right triangle(, then) the Pythagorean theorem holds.

Mixing them up (*if...then* versus *since...*)is a contamination.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please cite your source? And why the introduction of the synonymous "because" in your answer?

Comment: My source is some 30 years of speaking the language, using _since_, _if_ and _then_ :-) I introduced _because_ as a synonym because the word _since_ has several meanings, and turn out to be quite a confusing word for some people, in part because of those different meanings. In "since...then", I suspect both _since_ and _then_ seem to be interpreted in their temporal sense (from a certain moment ... after that).

Comment: Mr. Oerkelens was using the equivalency of "since" with "because" to demonstrate that your example equates to one that is obviously incorrect to any native speaker (for the reason he cited).

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Yes, that seems likely. But I don't think the version with "because" is more obviously wrong than the once with "since". Maybe it's because I've heard it too much, but it's not obvious to me that either are wrong, and I am a native speaker. Often things that feel wrong to me only do so because I rarely hear them. The point is that I'm still not fully convinced that it (either) is (are) wrong and would therefore like an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @oerkelens's answer, except that I would make an allowance for *since...then...* in cases where there is a lot of verbiage between the two words. such as a list of reasons, a list of steps in the reasoning, or parenthetical statements.

So if St. Paul had followed his usual style, this sentence:

> Therefore, since we have so great a cloud of witnesses surrounding us,
>   let us also lay aside every encumbrance...

might have looked like this:

> Therefore, **since** we have so great a cloud of witnesses surrounding us, including Abel, who offered to God a better sacrifice than Cain, through which he obtained the testimony that he was righteous, God testifying about his gifts, and through faith, though he is dead, he still speaks, **then** let us also lay aside every encumbrance...

Comment: +1 for threatening to overflow my English parsing stack. :)

Comment: @tchrist “Wouldn’t the sentence ‘I want to put a hyphen between the words Fish and And and And and Chips in my Fish-And-Chips sign’ have been clearer if quotation marks had been placed before Fish, and between Fish and and, and and and And, and And and and, and and and And, and And and and, and and and Chips, as well as after Chips?” - See more at: http://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2013/04/whats-the-best-sentence-ever-formed.html#sthash.togojftH.dpuf

Comment: Good point. However, it's still a bit of a mismatch between *since* implying that the condition is true and *then* usually treating it as hypothetical. *Therefore* would be much better for this purpose. All considered, I would say it's borderline grammatical when used in this way.

Answer (score 2):

As has been remarked "Since p, then q" is a corruption of "if p, then q". The latter is a hypothetical sentence (i.e. it expresses a hypothetical relationship between two states of affairs). "Since", however, is a premise indicator; you'd use it in an argument that is based in the actual state of affairs.

You can see both at work here: "We agreed two weeks ago that *if* I clean, (*then*) you clean. Since I in fact cleaned, you must clean."

I suppose that people might mix them up because the difference between hypotheticals and arguments is a subtle one and there are many logical parallels between the two.

I checked out the relevant definition of "then" in the American Heritage Dictionary: "As a consequence; therefore". Using substitution we can see how awkward the "since ..., then ..." construction is: "since [state of affairs], as a consequence [state of affairs]". It just strikes my native-speaker intution that "as a consequence" is preceded by a sentence expressing a state of affairs that is *not* in a subordinate clause.

Answer (score 1):

***Since* is never used with *then***.

Since has two meanings: "for the reason that" and "happening at a time subsequent to a reference time".

For the situation you describe, which uses the first meaning, think about rearranging the sentence: 
*The Pythagorean theorem holds, since it's a right triangle.*

In the second case, it's very obvious no "then" belongs:  *Since 1492, the ocean has been blue.*

Comment: But even an "If A, then B" sentence sounds wrong with "then" included when the conclusion is put before the premise; compare "B, if A" with "Then B, if A".

Answer (score 0):

The construction **'since A , then B'** seems fine to me.

'Since' is being used as a shorthand for a modens ponens type argument.

Premise 1. The Pythagorean relationship holds for all triangles.
Premise 2. (since) this is a right triangle.
Conclusion: the Pythagorean relationship holds (for this triangle)

Premise 1 is not explicitly stated , it is implicitly assumed.
"Since this is a right triangle, its sides satisfy the Pythagorean relationship "

Another example:
"Since I am at least 18 years of age and a citizen of United states, I can vote."
Here again we have an implicit syllogism.

1. All people who are 18+ and citizen can vote.
2. I am a person that is 18+ and a citizen.
   Conclusion : I can vote

I don't see how 'since' can mean the same thing as the hypothetical indicator 'if' used in conditional 'if-then' statements. 'Since' has a meaning that something in fact did happen. The 'if' part of a conditional does not in fact need to occur or be true. But when you say, 'since x, then y' you mean since x did in fact happen, y has to occur.

We can be even more explicit. Any 'since x then y' statement can be rewritten as 
"since x is the case in fact, then by logical necessity y is the case"

"Because it is a right triangle, then by logical necessity this triangle satisfies the Pythagorean relationship a^2 + b^2 = c^2"

I don't think we need to complicate issues by bringing in causality here, because showing cause and effect is a different matter. A right triangle does not 'cause' a theorem to be true in the sense of an agent cause, like my kicking a ball causes it to move. It is more like a matter of logical necessity; e.g. as a result of how we define right triangles on a Euclidean plane the Pythagorean relationship holds for all right triangles. Because x is an even integer, then x^2 is an even integer because of how we define even integers and the properties of algebra. Not because integers physically cause their squares to become even by some sort of phenomenon.

So to summarize
'since x, then y ' is equivalent in meaning to
'As a result of x being in fact true, then by logical necessity y must be true as well, (because we know that y is true whenever x is true)'. The last part in parentheses is often omitted.

Comment: This doesn’t actually seem to address the question at all, despite its length and detail. Nobody is doubting what _since A, then B_ means, nor why and how it differs from _if A, then B_. The question is simply to do with whether or not it is grammatical to have the word _there_ on the surface in the matrix clause.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question. Is the question whether the form **'since A, then B'** is the same as **'since A, B'**. I treat them as equivalent. You can leave out the comma if you use **'since A then B'**, but for readability **'since A, B'** a comma should be used. Also what do you mean by 'matrix clause'.

Comment: Yes, that is the question—or rather, whether it is even grammatical to have the _then_ there at all (some answers on the page say no; I would say grammatical, but clumsy-sounding in most contexts). A matrix clause is basically the same as a main or independent clause, here _(then) B_, as opposed to subordinate clause, here _since A_.

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* the usage is correct. Not citing any sources. Haven't done any research either. Yet, all I have to say is that instead of

> Since . . . , then . . .

it should be

> Since . . . , *therefore* . . .

In a sentence, the word *since* implies beginning of a cause / reason / argument. When you have stated your argument / the cause / a reason, you would follow it with your conclusion / effect / action.

What follows *then* in an English sentence in general is the decision to be made when a condition has been met. That is why *then* is a regular member of sentences beginning with *if* and not with *since*. For example:

> If the answer is not accepted, then make the OP an offer she can't refuse.

As mentioned in other answers too here, we can simply write the conclusion / effect / action even without mentioning *therefore*. Explaining my answer with a *therefore* in the sentence puts the sentence using *then* in contrast.

Comment: displayName, if you cannot submit an answer with citations and proof of research, then you should not submit an answer. After you spend some time giving quality answers based on tangible sources, then you will be able to comment. At that point, you can cite as few sources and do as little research as you'd like -- as long as you limit your input to the comment section.

Comment: @JakeRegier: Not that I cannot submit the answer with citations and proofs, it's just that my daily use of English language naturally led me to this answer. Since the 'Since.., therefore...' way of sentence framing was not only grammatically correct, but also colloquial, therefore I put it here without caring for research and citations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DogLover: I don't need any clarification on the question as I get what the OP is asking about. Why do you say that my answer above provide an answer to OP's question? What I have mentioned is an answer even though it doesn't have any associated links. Read the second comment on oerkelens answer.

Comment: @displayName Please don't take it personally - I was in a bit of a hurry so that was the best option at the time. The reason is because answers are meant to be known, rather than thought. Thoughts are usually reserved for comments :)

Comment: @DogLover: Not taking your point personally man. The thing is that 'English' is not a science like 'Chemistry' or 'Physics' that has to be supported by facts. English is a language, used for conveying thoughts. Therefore finding reasons to support a sentence structure is little unusual. General language usage and colloquialism is good enough argument for justification of a sentence structure.

Comment: @DogLover: Correct me if I am wrong. I will accept an argument from anyone if it is valid.

Comment: So you think "since A, therefore B" is correct? To me, it feels the same, and hence feels just as wrong, as "since A, then B" does.

Comment: If you are attempting to edit your own post, you need to log in with the same account used to create the post.

Comment: @jxh: The editor is my actual account. I logged in as a guest to answer the question as I wasn't on my laptop and didn't remember the password. Not trying to do anything fancy here. If you can get these two merged, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Since I rolled a 5 on a die, then you won the bounty.